# Parsing HLS manifest file videogular2

Tags: javascript, angular, video, http-live-streaming, videogular

I am trying to play a HLS live stream using videogular2. The video is playing fine however, it does not show the right time. I am guessing videogular2 should parse the .m3u8 manifest file and use the "EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME" header as an offset to the current time. It does not seem to be working that way.

Is there any way I can parse the file? Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Thank you for your question, could you provide a bit more detail to help this get answered. What have you already tried? Do you have some code you can share. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips about how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

[videogular2](/questions/tagged/videogular2) uses [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) which does support `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME`. Fragments have the `programDateTime` and `rawProgramDateTime` attributes. These are not used in the native video controls, you most likely need to implement your own custom controls. See the hls.js [demo](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/) (bottom).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I obtained the programDateTime by parsing it directly using hls.js. I was wondering if there is any way to get it from videogular2 itself. Also, I noticed a difference of around 18-20 seconds from the parsed value I obtained and the value I see in the response of the GET call.

Comment: @KshitijAgrawal did you check the program date time of the first fragment or a later one?

Comment: yes, it's the first fragment. 
I got it from here : data.levels[0].details.fragments[0].programDateTime